# Prove that the coefficients of a polynomial are in a finite field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I am trying to understand the proof of the following statement:

Let $\mathscr{θ}$ be an algebraic element over the finite field $F$ and $\mathscr{θ=θ_1,θ_2 ... θ_n}$ be all the conjugate elementes of $\mathscr{θ}$ over $F$. Also let $s(x)\in F[x]$ and $\mathscr{α}=s(\mathscr{θ})$ and $\mathscr{β}$ is conjugate element of $\mathscr{α}$ over $F$. Then $\mathscr{β}=s(θ_i)$ for some $1\leq i \leq n$.

Here is what the proof is:

Consider the polynomial $g(x)$ = $\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x-s(θ_i))$. This polynomial is monic and $g(x)\in F[x]$. Then let $f_\mathscr{α}\in F[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\mathscr{α}$. It follows from $g(\mathscr{α})=0$  that $f_\mathscr{α}(x)|g(x)$. Then all conjugate elements of $\mathscr{α}$ over $F$ (including $\mathscr{β}$) are amongst the roots of $g(x)$ which means they are $s(θ_i)$.

I don't know how to prove that $g(x)\in F[x]$. Actually there is a hint how to prove it - I should use a technique similar to the one used in another proof. And here is my atempt :

Let $K=F(\mathscr{θ_1,θ_2 ... θ_n})$ and $\mathscr{θ_1,θ_2 ... θ_n}$ are roots of $f(x)\in F[x]$. Next I need $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x-θ_i)$. If we assume that this is true then according to Viète theorem the coefficients of $f(x)$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials of the roots $\mathscr{θ_1,θ_2 ... θ_n}$ which means that the coefficients of $f(x)$ are elements of the field $F$. $g(x)$ = $\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x-s(θ_i))$ in other hand again according to Viète theorem has coefficients which are the elementary symmetric polynomials of the roots $s(θ_1),s(θ_2) ... s(θ_n)$. Each coefficient of $g(x)$ **should** be a symmetrical polynomial again and then I can use the *fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials* to prove that $g(x)\in F[x]$ but I can't find a solution. Perhaps this approach is wrong.

Any suggestions and explanations will be very much welcome!
Thank you!

Comment: Your approach is fine and don't you think you are already done? The coeffs of $g$ are symmetric in the $s(\theta_i)$ hence symmetric in the $\theta_i$, hence polynomials in the elementary symmetrics, hence in $F$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm unable to understand why the coefficients of $g$ are symmetric in $s\mathscr(θ_i)$ and hence symmetric in $\mathscr(θ_i)$. It is not obvious for me that the coefficients are symmetric.

Comment: I think the approach in the proof is unnecessarily complicated. Suppose that the field is $\mathbb F_q$. Then, $\theta_i\in\mathbb F_{q^n}$, and $\theta_i=\theta_1^{q^{i-1}},1\leq i\leq n$. For $s(x)\in\mathbb F_q[x]$, $$\alpha^q=\left(\sum_j s_j\theta_i^j\right)^q=\sum_j s_j^q\left(\theta_1^j\right)^q=\sum_j s_j\left(\theta_1^q\right)^j=\sum_j s_j \theta_2^j$$ since $s_j^q = s^j$ because $s_j\in \mathbb F_q$. Thus, the values of $s(\theta_i)$ are conjugates over $\mathbb F_q$.